# LFSR not working as intended

Tags: c, bit-shift, bit

As above, I've created a LFSR to try and generate some numbers, however it's not working properly.

Started with this:

```
unsigned int lfsr = 0x000001
while(1)
{
  lfsr >>= 1
  unsigned int lsb1 = lfsr & 1;
  unsigned int lsb2 = lfsr & 2;

  if (lsb1 == 1 && lsb2 == 1 || lsb1 == 0 && lsb2 == 0)
    lfsr |= 0x000000;
  else
    lfsr |= 0x800000;
}
```

However that didn't work, with lsb2 equaling 2, so after some mucking about I've currently got this:

```
unsigned int lfsr = 0x000001
while(1)
{
  lfsr >>= 1
  lfsr |= ( (((unsigned int)((lfsr<<31)>>31)) ^ ((unsigned int)((lfsr<<30)>>31))) << 24);
}
```

This generates 2^21 - 1 numbers, whereas I'm trying to get something that generates 2^24.

Am I missing something obvious?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `int` does not guarantee 32 bits. Use `stdint.h` types instead!

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with `lfsr |= 0x000000;`?

Comment: I guess LFSR means [Linear feedback shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register). The article on WIkipedia describes periods that are 1 less than a power of 2. Why do you expect a period of 2^24? (Please post a link that explains the theory)

Comment: @Olaf `lfsr |= 0x000000` is useful for clarity (maybe) or for balanced timing (yet likely will be defeated by any optimization).

Comment: Also, I don't understand the theory, but by looking [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf) I can vaguely guess that for period of `2^24-1` you cannot use a LFSR with 2 taps - you need 4.

Comment: chux is right, it was for clarity.Also I was basing it upon a picture in the paper here: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1629098 (not sure if you'll be able to see the paper). I may have misunderstood however, and yes that pdf does seem to indicate that, I'll do some testing and update, thanks!

Comment: @chux: I do not see it becomes any clearer (more clear?). And for timing, you already gave the answer (when needing specific timing, e.g. against timing attacks, you cannot rely on a compiler anyway) - do you really think OP got into that deep?

Comment: @GeorgeStorm: It is generally bad advice to copy something from some paper without actually know the reasons. Perhaps you should start at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register). Note that a proper implementation will never become `0`, thus never can produce all representable values. You can, however, use only a part of the register for the result. This is actually the recommended usage.

Comment: You normally only test a singe bit, the xor the whole with the generator in a software-implementation. You think of a hardware-implementation which works differently.

Comment: @Olaf  I suspected OP was referencing some other document.  As LFSR get into some interesting math, copying verbatim is a reasonable first step.  Many an LFSR is constructed in hardware and `lfsr |= 0x000000;` matches the hardware shifting in a carry into the MSBit.

Comment: @Olaf POSIX guarantees a 32 bit `int` though and OP could use an `unsigned long` for C89 compatibility instead.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Sorry, I seem to have missed the POSIX and C89 references somehow. Where was it mentioned, again? Even with POSIX: `uint32_t` is not just the corect type, but also a clear statement.

Comment: See [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html#tag_20_11_13_04) (command `c99` section *programming environments*). C89 specifies that a `long` goes to 2³¹-1 and an `unsigned long` to 2³² at least.

Comment: The LFSR wasn't the focus of the paper as a whole, just a small part of one of the algorithms I was trying to implement and so I foolishly saw the diagram and tried it. @Olaf you are indeed correct it was the diagram for the hardware implementation also in the paper, I missed that. Thanks for all of the help, I'll be trying the methods mentioned here this morning

Comment: @FUZxxl: I strongly doubt an `unsigned long` "goes to `2**32`"! But I assume you mean `2**32-1`. Point is, however, 1) OP does not use `unsigned long`, 2) a `long` might very well have 64 bits (e.g. on POSIX-64 bit architectures. 3) the masks (, text and comments) imply OP wants 32 bits. What is your problem with `uint32_t`? They are there for exactly  such applications. If your implementation does not provide `stdint.h`, thus is not even C99 compliant, complain to your vendor or get a modern compiler - C99 is >16 years old now!

Comment: @Olaf So it's okay that OP's code is not going to run on Windows XP? Microsoft only recently begun to ship a compiler that even tries to implement C99 features.

Comment: "... that even tries ..." I'm really impressed. Just after >16 years and with C11 being 4 years old already. For XP: **YES** Whoever still uses XP is doomed anyway. (Yet: were again did OP write he is using XP?) You are just speculating and this leads nowhere. I'm out of this nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These LFSR examples will cycle through (2^24)-1 numbers (all 2^24 numbers but zero). The first example is a Galois LFSR that xor's with (feedback polynomial) then shifts. The second example is a Galois LFSR that shifts then xor's with (feedback polynomial >> 1). The third example is a Fibonacci LFSR. Note that with a start_state of 0x000001, the value of *bit* for all three examples follows the same pattern, even though Galois LFSR and Fibonacci LFSR will follow different patterns. 0x100001b is the smallest feedback polynomial and 0x1c20001 is the largest 4 tap feedback polynomial for (2^24)-1 cycles.

This example follows the wiki Galios LFSR example with the xor done first:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
unsigned int period, bit, lfsr, start_state;
    period = 0;
    lfsr = start_state = 0x000001;
    do
    {
        bit = lfsr&1;               /* get bit */
        lfsr ^= (0-bit)&0x100001b;  /* toggle taps if bit was 1 */
        lfsr >>= 1;                 /* shift lfsr */
        ++period;
    }while(lfsr != start_state);
    printf("%x\n", period);         /* period will == 0xffffff */
    return(0);
}
```

This example follows the wiki Galios LFSR example with the shift done first:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
unsigned int period, bit, lfsr, start_state;
    period = 0;
    lfsr = start_state = 0x000001;
    do
    {
        bit = lfsr & 1;             /* get bit */
        lfsr >>= 1;                 /* shift lfsr */
        lfsr ^= (0-bit)&0x80000d;   /* toggle taps if bit was 1 */
        ++period;
    } while (lfsr != start_state);
    printf("%x\n", period);         /* period will == 0xffffff */
    return(0);
}
```

This example follows the wiki Fibonacci LFSR example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
unsigned int period, bit, lfsr, start_state;
    period = 0;
    lfsr = start_state = 0x000001;
    do
    {
        /* taps: 24 4 3 1 */
        /* feedback polynomial: x^24 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 = 0x100001b */
        bit  = ((lfsr>>(24-24))^(lfsr>>(24-4))^(lfsr>>(24-3))^(lfsr>>(24-1)))&1;
        lfsr =  (lfsr >> 1) | (bit << 23);
        ++period;
    } while (lfsr != start_state);
    printf("%x\n", period);         /* period will == 0xffffff */
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this certainly seems to work, going to do a bit more reading to see as to why, as it doesn't seem to correlate with the pdf that @anatolyg linked in his comment to my question.

Comment: @GeorgeStorm - I updated my answer, the first two examples use a [Galois LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register#Galois_LFSRs). The first example does the xor before the shift to show the 25 bit feedback polynomial (0x100001b). The second example follows the wiki example code. The third example uses a Fibonacci LFSR with the same feedback polynomial, similar to what your example code was doing. 0x100001b is the smallest poly and  0x1c20001 is the largest 4 tap poly for (2^24)-1 cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect code:  `lsb2 == 1` is never true

```
unsigned int lsb2 = lfsr & 2;
...
if (lsb1 == 1 && lsb2 == 1 ....  // bad
```

Likely should be

```
if (lsb1 && lsb2 ....  // better
```

---

Agree with [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4774918/olaf), consider `uint32_t`.

Comment: So I would need to shift the result right by one? I don't actually need 32 bits, only need 24, but thought there would be no harm in using 32 as all of the ones to the left of 24 would be 0 and wouldn't effect the numbers being generated.

Comment: @GeorgeStorm 1) Yes, an alternate could be to `unsigned int lsb2 = (lfsr & 2) >> 1;`  or `= !!(lfsr & 2);` or others.  2) Concerning 32 vs. 24 bit: `unsigned` is only _at least_ 16-bit.  Thus the suggestion to use an integer guaranteed to meet your 32/24 bit width needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int lfsr = 0x000001 // actually int is 4 bytes so result is 0x00000001
while(1)
{
  lfsr >>= 1                    // now lfsr = 0
  unsigned int lsb1 = lfsr & 1; // == 0
  unsigned int lsb2 = lfsr & 2; // == 0

   // the following line will 'work' however, it is always better/clearer
   // to force the correct precedence via parens
   // and lsb2 will be 0 or 2, never 1
  if (lsb1 == 1 && lsb2 == 1 || lsb1 == 0 && lsb2 == 0)
    lfsr |= 0x000000;  // this will always be executed and makes no change to the value in 'lfsr'
  else
    lfsr |= 0x800000;  // unsigned int is 4 bytes, so this is actually 0x00800000
}
```